# How to run multiple app using PM2?

Tags: node.js, angular, pm2

I want to run my angular4 app using **PM2** it will run but when I am close the **terminal** it will stop.

1. On this server already run one application, it is working properly,
   **but in my app it will work when I am open the terminal, otherwise it will stop**

   pm2 start server.js

I am using this command to run my app but when I am Close the Terminal immediately it will stop,
so how can I run this app Forever using PM2.

Comment: The question is misleading and conceals real problem. The purpose of PM2 is to run the app 'forever', regardless of whether terminal window is open or not.

Comment: @estus the other one is working properly but the second one is running stop when i close the Terminal, Do you have any proper solution? should i run this command as a ROOT?

Comment: @Chaudhary You still having problem??

Comment: @Vishantdhandha still having same problem.

Answer (score 14):

If you are using PM2 properly, your applications should not be turning off after terminal exit. It is very likely that your application is failing. Run `pm2 logs` to diagnose.

You can specify multiple applications in a `process.json` file like this:

```
{
    "apps" : [{
        "name"        : "worker",
        "script"      : "./worker.js",
        "watch"       : true,
        "env": {
            "NODE_ENV": "development"
        },
        "env_production" : {
            "NODE_ENV": "production"
        }
    },{
        "name"       : "api-app",
        "script"     : "./api.js",
        "instances"  : 4,
        "exec_mode"  : "cluster"
    }]
}
```

[Documentation Here](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/)

Started like this:

```
pm2 start process.json
```

And can monitor/view your applications by running `pm2 monit` or `pm2 ls`

Answer (score 5):

You can start any NodeJs server using `pm2 start ****.js --name "Project Name"`.
[image]

You can check that server is online or not.

Comment: still having same issue, it will work but when i close the Terminal it will Stop.

Comment: Did you check the status?

Comment: @Yoesh Patel when i run this Command from ROOT it will works fine, thanxx

Answer (score 2):

If you are running the same script multiple times, with different parameters for instance, just give them different names.

i.e.

PM2 Start Engage.js --name Warp1

PM2 Start Engage.js --name Warp2

PM2 Start Engage.js --name Impulse