# Running two react clients on PM2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, pm2

I'm trying to run two clients with npm start on pm2, but I'm not figuring out a way to create a sort of alias to each of them.
They are both running on different ports and I was trying to use

```
pm2 start npm
```

on each of them, but it only starts one and ignores the other

Comment: did you followed this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47919811/how-to-run-multiple-app-using-pm2 ?

Answer (score 0):

we can add the list of applications which is running in a different port. This is the sample process.json in my project. Here API is running in 3001 port and storeapp is running on 3000 port.

````
        {
            "name": "api",
            "script": "./src/api/server/index.js",
            "node_args": "-r esm",
            "watch": ["./config/server.js", "./src/api/server/"],
            "instances": "1",
            "exec_mode": "fork",
            "watch_options": {
                "persistent": true,
                "ignoreInitial": false
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "storeapp",
            "script": "./dist/store/server/index.js",
            "node_args": "-r esm",
            "watch": [
                "./config/server.js",
                "./theme/assets/index.html"
            ],
            "instances": "1",
            "exec_mode": "fork",
            "watch_options": {
                "persistent": true,
                "ignoreInitial": false
            }
        }
    ]
}

```
````