# Run multiple node project with single command, each project situated in different folder

Tags: node.js

I'm working on a project which has 4 different repos. To run the project I've to start the node server separately. Here is the current structure

Main Folder

- Project 1
- Project 2
- Project 3
- Project 4

Is there any way to start all the server with single command?
PS: All projects are using same command to start the server on different port.

Just expecting to execute the single command to run all the server, as nodemon in also in place so if I change any code on any project it'll hot reload.

Comment: You should try to solve this yourself first. That said, nodemon should be able to solve your issue. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the shell mechanism and its background task feature, which allows you to run commands simultaneously.

#### Definition

To [run a command in Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44222883/run-a-shell-script-and-immediately-background-it-however-keep-the-ability-to-in), on *NIX, append `&` at the end of the command line:

```bash
npm run dev &
```

On [Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/198525/how-can-i-execute-a-windows-command-line-in-background), however, the syntax is different:

```
START /B npm run dev
```

*Based on your folder names, I assume you are on Windows.*

#### Run script (Windows)

In the `Main Folder`, where all projects are put, add a batch file named `run-script.bat` with the following content:

```
cd "Project 1"
START /B npm run dev

cd ..
cd "Project 2"
START /B npm run dev

cd ..
cd "Project 3"
START /B npm run dev

cd ..
cd "Project 4"
START /B npm run dev
```

By clicking on the batch file, all projects get run at the same time. I, also, assumed your run command is `npm run dev`, change it to fit (maybe yours is `npm start` or `nodemon .`).

#### Bash script (*NIX)

In the `Main Folder`, where all projects are put, add a script file named `run-script.sh` with the following content:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
cd "Project 1"
npm run dev &

cd ..
cd "Project 2"
npm run dev &

cd ..
cd "Project 3"
npm run dev &

cd ..
cd "Project 4"
npm run dev &
```

Open a shell script and [make the script executable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/229589/how-to-make-a-file-e-g-a-sh-script-executable-so-it-can-be-run-from-a-termi) using:

```bash
chmod +x run-script.sh
```

Now, you are free to run the script.

```bash
./run-script.sh
```

#### Production

For production or in advanced cases it is better to use tools such as [PM2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47919811/how-to-run-multiple-app-using-pm2).